# I want to use insert query in mysql using php where some fields are array and other are simple field including auto increment field

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php and I want to insert data into using insert query where 2 fields that is size and numberofitems are array and other are normal fields and id is autoincrement in my database.It is giving failure when i run this code.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','user');
define('PASS','pass');
define('DB','db');


$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
include 'filename.php';
include 'filename1.php'; 

$item=$_POST['url'];
$color=$_POST['color'];
$date1=date("Y-m-d");       
echo 'working3';

$s=array($_POST['size']);
$s1=array($_POST['numberofitems']);
if(is_array($s)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO placeorder VALUES ";
    $valuesArr = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($s); $i++){

        echo 'working4';         

        $size = mysqli_real_escape_string( $s[$i] );
        $n = mysqli_real_escape_string( $s1[$i] );
        $valuesArr[] = "('$contact','$name','$item','$color','$size','$n','$date1')";
        echo $valuesArr[$i];
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo"success";
    }else
        echo"failure";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Sensible code indentation helps us read your script but more importantly helps **you** debug your code

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you mean `size` and `numberofitems` are arrays on the HTML form?

Comment: size and numberofitems are arraylist from android..

Comment: All the posted values are coming from android and the error is i am getting failure.

Comment: When asking a question that involves posting code, always include the results of running your code in the question text.

Comment: Then you dont need to do `$s=array($_POST['size']);` add a `echo print_r($_POST)` to the top of your script and view the results back in the android debugger to see what PHP see's in the `$_POST` array

Comment: I checked all the values are posting correctly but i guess there is some problem in php code.

Comment: My $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql); is returning false when I var_dump $result .Please suggest some problem.I am going nuts.